# VSCode django: property value expectedcss(css-propertyvalueexpected)

Tags: html, django, visual-studio-code

В [visual-studio-code](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) та переменная, что внутри `style`, подсвечивается ошибкой, хотя и выполняется, но всё красным-красно. Как пофиксить?

```html
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: {{user.getSearchRating}}%"></div>
</div>
```

Вот скриншот:

[image: скрин]